# Adding elapsed time in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, time

In Cocoa, how would I add times for example:

1:30 (one hour and 30 minutes)
1:25 (one hour and 25 minutes)
2:15 (two hour and 15 minutes)

= 5:10

but when I get to greater then 24 hours I do not want it to go, one day x hours and y mins, I want it to continue adding the hours e.g. 25, 26, 27 ... 100 hours etc. Is there already an implemented method in Cocoa?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them yourself in a [date components](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/) object.

When you add two seconds components together, divide by 60 to determine the number to carry to the minutes component, and use the `%` operator to determine the new value of the seconds component. (For example, 73 seconds is `73 / 60` = 1 minute and `73 % 60` = 13 seconds.) Do likewise for adding minutes and carrying to hours. Then, when adding hours, just add them and don't do any divmod magic if you don't want to carry to the days component.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836).

Answer (score 0):

Just for other peoples interest using Peter Hoseys advice heres my simple command line tool which solves this problem: (if anyone has any tips for bettering my solution it would be very much appreciated). Also is there any advantage to using the `remainder function` over the `%`?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSDateComponents *totalTime;

void timeByAddingComponents(NSDateComponents *firstTime, NSDateComponents *secondTime) {
    int addMin = [firstTime minute] + [secondTime minute];
    int addHour = floor(addMin/60);
    addMin = addMin % 60;
    addHour = addHour + [firstTime hour] + [secondTime hour];
    [totalTime setMinute:addMin];
    [totalTime setHour:addHour];
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    totalTime = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [totalTime setHour:0];
    [totalTime setMinute:0];

    NSDateComponents *addTime = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    while (TRUE) {
        int x, y;
        printf("Please Enter Number of Hours: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        printf("Please Enter Number of Minutes: ");
        scanf("%d", &y);
        if (x == 0 && y == 0)
            break;
        NSLog(@"Add %i:%i to %i:%i", x,y, [totalTime hour], [totalTime minute]);
        [addTime setHour:x];
        [addTime setMinute:y];
        timeByAddingComponents(totalTime, addTime);
        NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d",[totalTime hour],[totalTime minute]];
        NSLog(@"Total time now: %@", time);
    }

    [totalTime release];
    [addTime release];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `%` operator doesn't work on floating-point types. For integral types, you absolutely should use `%`. (I'd forgotten that NSDateComponents uses integers for the component values. You can skip the `floor` function; you would only need it when doing this with floating-point values.) Also, if you're not targeting Tiger, you should use `NSInteger` for these variables, not `int`. It's unlikely to ever matter in this case, but it's good to get into the habit as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I am only using this time for the purposes of adding to gain a total, would it be better to use a C Sturct like below then NSDateComponents?

```
typedef struct {
   int    hours;
   int    minutes;
} time;
```

Comment: Since this doesn't answer the question, you should ask it as a separate question.